# c++ heavy data processing and paging

Tags: c++, windows, paging, virtual-functions

I'm writing an application that should process large ammounts of data (between 1-10 GB) as realtime as possible.

the data is present in multiple binary data files on harddisk, each between few kb and 128MB. when the process starts, first it is decided which data is actually needed. then some user settings are taken through the userinterface and then the data is processed chunk by chunk where always a file is loaded into memory, processed, and then cleared from the memory. this processing should be fast because the user can change some settings and then the same data is reprocessed and this user interaction should be as fluent as possible.

Now the loading from disk is quite some bottleneck and I would like to preload the data already at the stage where it's decided what files will be used. however - if I preload too much data, the os will use virtual memory and i'll have plenty of pagefaults, making the processing even slower.

how can I determine how much data to preload in order to keep pagefaults low? can I influence the os somehow on what data I want to keep in memory?

thanks!

//edit: i'm currently running on Windows 7 64 (the application is 32bit however) and the application does not need to run on any computer - only on a specific one since this is a research project.

Comment: You should specify the OS as the answer might very well get platform specific

Answer (score 3):

For a general case random access to large binary files I would consider using native OS file memory mapping API. This will most probably be the most efficient solution from performance perspective, there is also a system API available in most OS-es to lock a page in memory, but I wouldn't use it. When doing something more specific, it is possible in most cases to have a smart indexing to know exactly what is where and solve most performance bottlenecks by that.

And yes, there is no magic, if you need all 10G available in RAM because they are accessed equally often, get 16GB of RAM on your box.

Comment: Many OSes allow some hints about how you plan to access memory mapped files - i.e. sequential access, random access etc. - that they'll use to decide on a caching approach.  Also, memory mapping runs afoul of the fact the question specifies a 32-bit app - personally, I'd look very seriously at porting it to 64-bit then letting the OS handle the caching and faulting.  To increase the chance of having the right pages in memory, think about the odds of any particualr page being used next, if non-equal do something to fault it in preemptively.

Answer (score 2):

For a Windows platform, I would recommend you look into :

- [MapViewOfFile function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366761%28VS.85%29.aspx) : *maps a view of a file mapping into the address space of a calling process*
- [I/O Completion Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198%28VS.85%29.aspx) : *an efficient threading model for processing multiple asynchronous I/O requests on a multiprocessor system*

Answer (score 1):

There is a file mapping support in [boost::interprocess](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_file)